# How to update Opencv3.3?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I already have installed OpenCV 3.3 with python3 on my Macbook in a virtual environment. I want to update to OpenCV 3.4. I had installed OpenCV 3.3 by following https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/ tutorial.
How to do this?